# How do I add this prolog to my .pl file?

Tags: prolog, predicate, discrete-mathematics

I am just starting to learn prolog.  I am learning it for my CS 2300 class.  I am trying to learn the basics right now.  How do I add a predicate to my .pl file?  I am just trying to add a predicate to my .pl file.  I am doing this:

`married(X,Y) :- married(Y,X).`

And I get the errors:

```
ERROR: Undefined procedure: (:-)/2
ERROR: Rules must be loaded from a file
ERROR: See FAQ at http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.tx
```

Am I supposed to enable this somehow?

This is the given `.pl` file:

```
% File FAMILY.PL
% Part of a family tree expressed in Prolog
% In father/2, mother/2, and parent/2,
% first arg. is parent and second arg. is child.

father(michael,cathy).
father(michael,sharon).
father(charles_gordon,michael).
father(charles_gordon,julie).
father(charles,charles_gordon).
father(jim,melody).
father(jim,crystal).
father(elmo,jim).
father(greg,stephanie).
father(greg,danielle).

mother(melody,cathy).
mother(melody,sharon).
mother(hazel,michael).
mother(hazel,julie).
mother(eleanor,melody).
mother(eleanor,crystal).
mother(crystal,stephanie).
mother(crystal,danielle).

parent(X,Y) :- father(X,Y).
parent(X,Y) :- mother(X,Y).
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to write what are predicates by using word predicates before all predicates.

predicates , clauses are keyword in prolog. you have to use that key word as well.

you can refer this link for family relation program.

http://www.dailyfreecode.com/Code/prolog-find-relations-family-3025.aspx

if you are new to prolog.

```
predicates 
father (symbol,symbol).
clauses 
father(michael,cathy).
```

try this code.

Comment: I just got this: predicate married(X,Y).
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: predicate 
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: married(X,Y) .

Comment: if you are new in prolog then dont write or use whole code.
    predicates 
    father (symbol,symbol).
    clauses 
    father(michael,cathy).

try to compile this. you will get an idea how it actually works.

Comment: Gotcha, I was thinking I could add stuff to the knowledge base after compiling.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: The user's error message is from SWI-Prolog, but your answer pertains to Visual Prolog, which is not ISO and probably should not be called "Prolog" by itself, alone.

Answer (score 2):

What's happened here is you're trying to enter rules at a query prompt. This is what you're experiencing:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 6.2.6)
Copyright (c) 1990-2012 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- parent(X,Y) :- father(X,Y).
ERROR: Undefined procedure: (:-)/2
ERROR:   Rules must be loaded from a file
ERROR:   See FAQ at http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/ToplevelMode.txt
?-
```

Notice that I have the exact same error message there as you do. Prolog distinguishes between queries and consulting database. What you want to do is consult. Put all your stuff into a file and name it `family.pl`, and then do this:

```
?- [family].
```

You should see this result:

```
% family compiled 0.00 sec, 21 clauses
true.

?-
```

If you want to enter rules and facts interactively, consult "user" like so:

```
?- [user].
|: foo(X) :- bar(X).
|: <Ctrl-D>
% user://1 compiled 0.00 sec, 2 clauses
true.
```

Notice that the `<Ctrl-D>` there is typing D while holding the Control key down, not literally typing that text.

As for the other answer, it pertains to Visual Prolog *only*, and therefore has nothing to do with your problem. Many Prologs implement the ISO standard and you can expect them to behave similarly or identically depending on the input. SWI and GNU are some of the more popular ISO Prolog implementations. However, Visual Prolog is a *completely different language* and should not be called "Prolog" in passing.